# how to add an exception in .htaccess file php for wordpress blog

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, dns

I have a website, www.test.com which is written in PHP and I have a wordpress blog, www.test.com/blog. Now I have rectified the WWW resolve for the main website, i.e., test.com is permanently redirected to www.test.com.

The problem here is when I run, www.test.com/blog, the browser is displaying this error message, 'This webpage has a redirect loop'.

Now my blog is not online. Please tell me how to rectify this problem.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to permalink setting in your wordpress.

Look into wp-options table of your WP (via backend MySQL) and make sure site and home URLs are starting with `www.test.com`.

Comment: The difficulty here is i am not able to log-in into the www.test.com/blog, so very tricky problem here, how can I get over it?

Comment: That's why I wrote `via backend MySQL)` in my answer. You will need to update wp-options table from phpMyAdmin or some other MySQL client.

Comment: Thank you very much, my colleagues have solved this problem, now my blog is running on browser.